# What exactly should I change in this snip of code to have ability set a path to a save file?

Tags: java, android, path, zip, unzip

Help me please

I really can't understand how to change this snip of code to have ability set a path to save file.

I need unzip a file. I want give the method 2 arguments: the first is the path to the zip file and the second is the path where you want to store the unzipped file. That's it... But it's driving me crazy))

I have the code

```
public class Decompress {
private String zipFile;
private String location;
private final String MY_LOG = "Decompress";

public Decompress(String zipFile, String location) {
    this.zipFile = zipFile;
    this.location = location;
    dirChecker("");
}

public void unzip() {
    try {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(fin);
        ZipEntry ze;

        while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            Log.e(MY_LOG, "Unzipping " + ze.getName());

            if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                dirChecker(ze.getName());
            } else {

                write(zis, new FileOutputStream(location + ze.getName()));
                zis.closeEntry();
            }
        }
        zis.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(MY_LOG, "unzip", e);
    }
}

private void write(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;

    while ((len = in.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    out.close();
}

private void dirChecker(String dir) {
    File f = new File(location + dir);
    if (!f.isDirectory()) {
        f.mkdirs();
    }
}
```

I set this in the constructor

```
zipFile = /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.android.camera2basic.demo/files/ttt@gmail.com/AvatarModelDir/new.zip
```

and I need to unzip this `new.zip` inside the current directory `AvatarModelDir`. According to this, I set...

```
location = /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.android.camera2basic.demo/files/ttt@gmail.com/AvatarModelDir
```

And I expect that the new path for unzip files will be like this

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.android.camera2basic.demo/files/ttt@gmail.com/AvatarModelDir/MyUnzip/Anna.dae
```

but instead, it creates this directory

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.android.camera2basic.demo/files/ttt@gmail.com/AvatarModelDirAnna/Anna.dae
```

Why it appent `Anna` to `AvatarModelDir` and why it create dir on level `ttt@gmail.com` instead of `AvatarModelDir`

I just need set the path to the `zip` file and the path where I want to unzip it in to (Extract Directory)

I expect the set path to unzip for example

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.android.camera2basic.demo/files/ttt@gmail.com/AvatarModelDir
```

and it should create a `Default name dirictory` inside `AvatarModelDir` and unzip current zip file

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.android.camera2basic.demo/files/ttt@gmail.com/AvatarModelDir/DefaultNameDirectory/...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside dirChecker Method

```
File f = new File(location + dir);
```

location and dir are concatenating instead of creating a new path for the new directory.

It should be like

```
String path = location + (!dir.isEmpty()?"/"+dir:"");
File f = new File(path);
```

Inside Decompress Constructor set the dir name that you want to be set.

```
dirChecker("MyUnzip");
```

Comment: i followed you suggest, and make changes in `dirChecker()` as you said and in Constructor, but i got `FileNotFoundException` in this line `write(zis, new FileOutputStream(location + ze.getName()));` how it is possible? There are files 100%

Comment: I forgot to mention the another change **write(zis, new FileOutputStream(location +"/"+ ze.getName()))**;

Comment: Yes! Really Thanks, i spend a lot of time try to understand how it work... But i remove "MyUnzip" from constructor because it create 2 dir : 1 - MyUnzip (without anything inside) and 2 - Anna (with files). I remove  "MyUnzip" and all is ok. I have such path `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.android.camera2basic.demo/files/ttt@gmail.com/AvatarModelDir/Anna/` .